# Having trouble testing for mobs with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a pokeball in Minecraft but I was wondering if there is any way for the command block to test for all mobs in a certain radius and give a different output depending on the mob without having to test for each mob individually with individual command blocks

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2):

update for 1.13;

```
/execute if entity @e[type=!player,distance=5] run <command>
```

you can potentially stack `if/unless` statements in there if you want more, but this is the shortened way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
/testfor @e[type=!player,r=RADIUS]
```

This will test for all mobs that are not players in the chosen RADIUS.

Otherwise there is no way to do what you are asking besides doing individual mobs.